# How to use TrustedRedirectResponse()?

Tags: 8, forms, redirection

I have used the following code on submit of a form to first send the form contents via guzzle and then redirect the form.  I get the error

```
Error: Call to undefined function TrustedRedirectResponse()
```

this is my code:

```
use Drupal\Core\Routing\TrustedRedirectResponse;

function mymodule_submit(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state){
$url="xyz.com";
$post_data=array("color"=>"red");

$client = \Drupal::httpClient();
  $response = $client->request('POST', $url, [
    'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'],
     'verify'=>false,
    'form_params' => $post_data,

     ]);
    $status = $response->getStatusCode();

    $response = TrustedRedirectResponse(Url::fromUri($url));
    $form_state->setResponse($response);
}
```

I have two questions - how can I avoid the error , and is the order of getting the guzzle response and then getting the redirect response the correct order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your order seems correct, you need to instanciate a new TrustedRedirectResponse object like:

```
$response = new TrustedRedirectResponse($url_string);
```

Answer (score -2):

The client->request is then unnecessary

```
 function my_module_submit(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
      $block = Block::load('bid');
      $block_settings = $block->get('settings');
      $url = $block_settings['url'];
      $query=$form_state->getValue('search_query');
      if (!empty($query)) {
        $url .= $query;
      }
      $response = new TrustedRedirectResponse($url);
      $form_state->setResponse($response);
    }
```

Comment: This answer is just duplication and does not provide any useful information. `$client->request()` is just part of the surrounding example code, just like `$block = Block::load('bid');` in your anwer is an example for block loading and unnecessary for a trusted response.